# Width of even divs are reduced when floated

Tags: html, css

Suppose the html code is

```html
  <div style="margin-left:10px;float: left; height:90px; width:0.5px;background-color:black;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; height:90px; width:0.5px;background-color:black;margin-left:20px;"></div>
```

I only see one div with width 0.5px.
But If I change the width of second div to 1px then both are visible.

Could someone give me an explanation about what is happening here.

Comment: Working with non-integer pixel values is not a good idea. A pixel is a pixel. It can't just divide itself.

Comment: A pixel is equal to the size of the smallest controllable element on a screen, you cannot render sub pixels as the screen cannot handle it (the browser will try to compensate but may handle it differently depending on the browser) - have a google for render sub pixel to learn more